# Login using facebook connect question

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement facebook connect on my site. I have used the oauth api to obtain a permissions request for the app.

However, I am having the following problem.

If a user signs into my site for the first time using facebook connect, i need to create a new username / password for him (on my site) to be able to surf my site and have all the session variables set. However, what should i use as the username / password ?
I understand that a facebook user can change his email address.

How do i handle users who are logging in using facebook connect for the second or third time (who are already members of my site) ? I need not create a user for them on my site as its already created when he logged in for the first time. Do i check for email address to see if the facebook user's email address exists in the database ? Also, comes the same problem that a facebook user can change his email address.

What is the one thing that does not change for a facebook user that i can use for his username ? Also, what do i use for his password ? Also, i understand that if i use username/password from available app data, then using normal mechanism a user can login to my site too. How do i prevent this security hole ?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the information that facebook send in the callback (facebook unique user id or normal id)and then check if the user is on my database, if not i insert him but i leaving blank the othe rstuff like password or user email (also you can request that info too check the line 418 in the php api and add "'req_perms' => 'email',")because i can retrive that data when they connect again and then set the sessions like allways.
if the users change teh email just check that on every login and update the data.
example:

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    $me = null;
    // Session based API call.
    if ($session) {
      try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
      }
    }


    // login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($me) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
    if ($me) {

    if (!isset($_SESSION["usr_id"])){
     $_SESSION["usr_id"] =$me['id'];
      $_SESSION["usr_name"]=$me['name'];

// or do your sql verification and then set the sessions 

        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate. Your answer really helped. I had almost given up on this. :)

Comment: If you have more questions we all are here to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook offers user's unique ID. You can recognize user with this information.